# Non-recursive alternative to XSLT identity transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering if there is a non-recursive alternative to the simple and clean recursive XSLT identity transformation (below)? I have been told XSLT recursive templates can have an impact on performance so I might not be allowed to use them in my current project.

Identity transformation template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't use recursion you can't use XSLT. Your source is misinformed.

Comment: Whoever told you that was wrong. Just because some uses of recursive templates have performance issues, doesn't mean all do, and it's certainly not a good argument to avoid them. It's not like you need to worry about being attacked by raptors or anything..

Comment: Premature raptor avoidance is the root of all evil.

Comment: I'm not saying it is true at all; in fact I don't agree with it, given that as Michael commented, XSLT processing model is recursive, and without recursivity, you lose most of the power that XLST offers. This discussion is what I think I was looking for, to gather some arguments against that misleading statement I've been told. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what's meant by 'recursive template'. Certainly if you have a named template that processes each character in some text in turn by dealing with substring($param,1,1), and recursive calling with substring($param,2,reallybigint), you're going to hit performance issues, but you can divide & conquer that sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

The question itself is misguided.

Express your transformation in its most elegant form, let the XSLT processor worry about optimizations, actually ***measure*** performance -- **don't guess**, and then optimize actual bottlenecks.

Chances are good that you'll have no performance problems requiring further attention anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY want to avoid recursion, you've basically got three options:

- Use one template, matching the document (`/`) and do all your output
  inside that template, without any use of `<xsl:apply-templates>`.
  However, this is exceptionally bad XSLT design.
- Use a literal result element- Your entire stylesheet is actually just
  output xml/html, but with the xsl namespace declared, and at key
  points using an `<xsl:value-of/>` instruction. EDIT: Thinking about it, this is pretty much the same as the first option.
- Refuse the task, if you can (recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear. The identity transform is used because it provides an opportunity to override it for some nodes by using another, more specific, template. This is possible *because* the identity transform is recursive.

If you only want to copy everything as is, without any exceptions, you could use simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Whether this will improve performance is another question.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I do want to override it for some nodes, so what I'm trying to get clear myself is if that would be impossible unless using recursive templates.

Comment: Well, you could process some branches recursively (or hierarchically), and deep-copy others. Keep in mind that the [XSLT processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model) is recursive, at least conceptually.